# Getting float values from a vector

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios5, vector, xcode4

I have little or no experience on C++ so question may sound wierd, the problem is that I have a std::vector containing float values, I want to extract float values from it by iterating it.

The definition code for the vector is like:

```
template <typename T, size_t feature_number>
  T vector_distance(const boost::array<T, feature_number>& v1,
                    const boost::array<T, feature_number>& v2);

  template <typename T = double, size_t feature_number=3>
  class CLASSNAME
  {
  public:
    typedef boost::array<T, feature_number> FeatureVector;
    typedef std::vector<FeatureVector> Features;
    ...
```

I am using it in the following way:

```
FeatureTypeDTW::Features mfcc_features_a = METHODTHATRETURNSVECTOR();

    for (int s = 0; s < (int) mfcc_features_a.size(); s++)
    {
        float MYFLOAT = mfcc_features_a[s];
    }
```

But the compile error that i get is:

> No viable conversion from 'boost::array (float, 7)' to 'float'

Any hints for how to convert??

Comment: The vector doesn't seem to contain floats, by arrays of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mfcc_features_a` is of type `Features`, which is a `vector` of `FeatureVector`s; the latter is in turn an alias for `boost::array<T, feature_number>`.

In short, you're trying to assign a `boost::array<T, feature_number>` to a `float`. Now, assuming the template argument `T` for `FeatureTypeDTW` is a `float` (or something convertible to a floating point number) this should work.

```
float MYFLOAT = mfcc_features_a[s][0];  // assigns first element of boost::array
                                        // to MYFLOAT
```

Comment: whats the second element? is it useful to me? i mean if it is a two dimensional vector then i should consider it

Comment: @Firdous How would I know that? From the error message it looks like the array contains 7 elements. Any / all of them may / may not be useful to you, that's for you to decide.

Comment: right just tell me that each mfcc_features_a[index] would contain 1 value or seven values in other dimension? is it a 2D array? have no knowledge of vectors :)

Comment: @Firdous Each `mfcc_features_a[index]` will contain a `boost::array` containing 7 elements. You can index into these using `mfcc_features_a[index][0] ... mfcc_features_a[index][6]`

Comment: if you could guide more will be great that I actually want to store this vector in plain text for furthur usage later, so is it as simple as a 2D array where I could insert two loops to read the vector and write in plain text and later read back the plain text to write the vector again using two loops? is it that simple doing with vectors?

Comment: @Firdous Sure, that's not difficult to do. Search on SO for vector serialization, and if you run into trouble post another question. It's beyond the scope of explaining in comments.